# Массивы в PHP

Tags: php

Как в один a.php вставить два других b.php  и c.php .

Из их содержания получить массивы, которые потом можно слить в один массив(array_merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a.php:

```
$array = array_merge(
    include ('b.php'),
    include ('c.php')
);
```

b.php:

```
return array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
```

c.php:

```
return array('d' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6);
```

Comment: Спасибо,не знал что можно делать array_merge(
    include ('b.php'),
    include ('c.php')
);
Буду знать!

Answer (score 1):

Инклюдяца так:

```
<?php
include("b.php");
include("c.php");
?>
```

А что в них за содержимое та?

Comment: значения обычные.
А про include() я знал.
Не знаю как слить в один массив полученные два)